# Shell scripting and regular expressions (sed, awk, grep...?)

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk, grep

Let's say I have a file that looks like this:

```
user ID   time started  time ended yes/no 
3523         15:00          0        yes  
2356         12:13       12:18       yes  
4690         09:10          0        no
```

I want to write  shell script that will pick out all of the lines in the file that
have a time ended of '0' and 'yes'.

For this example it'd be the first line only:

```
3523     15:00       0        yes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk '$3 == "0" && $4 == "yes" { print; }' myfile`

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize how simple this is to do with awk. As a side question before the print statement do you have to write END ?

Comment: Take a look at the man page for awk.  An awk script is basically a list of CONDITION ACTION pairs. In this case, the condition is $3=0 and $4=yes.  The corresponding action is print.  END is a condition that is true after the last line of the file is read.  So, any actions placed after that will only happen at the end of the file.  At that point, print will have no line to show.  In practice, other clauses would have stored values in globals for END's actions to make use of.

Comment: When you get comfortable with awk, you may want to remove the `{print}` body (which is the default action): `awk '$3==0 && $4=="yes"' file`

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -E '^[^ ]+ +[^ ]+ +0 +yes$' inputfile
```

or

```
grep -E '^([^ ]+ +){2}0 +yes$' inputfile
```

or

```
sed -n '/^\([^ ]\+ \+\)\{2\}0 \+yes$/p' inputfile
```

or

```
sed -nr '/^([^ ]+ +){2}0 +yes$/p' inputfile
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
 sed '/\s0\s\+yes\s*$/!d' inputfile
```

Answer (score 1):

this will work as well

`grep '............................0........yes' myfile`